# Error: "argument is not an atomic vector; coercing[1] FALSE"

Tags: r, vector, atomic, stringr

I'm new to R and am having trouble (1) generalizing previous stack overflow answers to my situation, and (2) understanding R documentation. So I turn to this community and hope someone will walk me through.

---

I have this code where `data1` is a text file:

```
data1 <- read.delim(file.choose())
pattern <- c("An Error Has Occurred!")
str_detect(data1, regex(pattern, ignore_case = FALSE))
```

The error message I see is:

```
argument is not an atomic vector; coercing[1] FALSE
```

When I use is.vector() to confirm the data type, it looks like it should be fine:

```
is.vector(pattern)
#this returns [1] TRUE as the output
```

Reference I used for str_detect function is https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_detect.

---

**Edit 1:** Here is the output of `data1` - I'm trying to match the 4th to last line "An Error Has Occurred!":

```
Silk.Road.Forums
<fctr>
*
Welcome, Guest. Please login or register.
[ ] [ ] [Forever] [Login]
Login with username, password and session length
[ ] [Search]
â\200¢ Home
â\200¢ Search
â\200¢ Login
â\200¢ Register
â\200¢ Silk Road Forums
An Error Has Occurred!
The user whose profile you are trying to view does not exist.
Back
â\200¢ SMF | SMF Â© 2013, Simple Machines
```

---

**Edit 2:** After a bit of rudimentary testing, it looks like the issue is with how I opened up `data1`, not necessarily `str_detect()`.

When I just create a vector, it works:

```
dataVector <- c("An Error Has Occurred!", "another one")
pattern <- c("An Error Has Occurred!")
str_detect(dataVector, pattern) # returns [1] TRUE FALSE
```

But when I try to use the function on the file, it doesn't

```
data1 <- read.delim(file.choose())
pattern <- c("An Error Has Occurred!")
str_detect(data1, pattern) # returns the atomic vector error message`
```

**Problem:** So I'm convinced that the problem is that (1) I'm using the wrong function or (2) I'm loading up the file wrong for this file type. I've never used text files in R before so I'm a bit lost.

---

That's all I have and thank you in advance for anyone willing to take a stab at helping!

Comment: Can you post an example of your data? E.g. the output of `data1`.

Comment: Absolutely -- thanks for replying @Muon. I'll edit within the post to make it easier to read. (Edit: I added the output in the question)

Comment: Thanks @bob. One more thing. Can you tell me the output of `class(data1)`?

Comment: @Moun, it comes out as `[1] "data.frame"` and I added more info in the question too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what is going on here is that `read.delim` is reading in your text file as a data frame and not a vector which is what `str_detect` requires.

For a quick work around you can try.

```
str_detect(data1[,1], "An Error Has Occurred!")
```

This works because right now data1 is a 1 column data frame. `data2[,1]` returns all rows for the first (and only) column of that data frame and returns it as a vector.

However! The problem here is you are using `read.delim` which is for delimited text files (i.e. like a csv file that has a separator such ',') which your data is not. Much better would be to use the function `readlines` which will return you a character vector.

```
# open a connection to your file
con <- file('path/to/file.txt',open="r")
# read file contents
data1 <- readLines(con)
# close the connection
close(con)
```

Then `str_detect` should work.

```
str_detect(data1, "An Error Has Occurred!")
```

Comment: No problem @bob! Best of luck with your project. R can have a steep learning curve. One thing to remember if you're having issues is to check that your data types are correct. The `class` function is very useful for this.

Answer (score 0):

Just as.data.frame() your data, the the str_replace() works fine!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).